# How to run gherkin style test cases in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework, gherkin

Is there some configuration setting that I must perform to get Robot Framework (RF) to run Gherkin/BDD style test cases?

I have installed RF 2.8.3 on Windows 7 and is running OK with Selenium2Library and DatabaseLibrary. According to the user docs and other info on the web, I should be able to write and run Gherkin style tests. However, when I do this, I get errors. RF does not strip the Gherkin keywords (Given, When, Then, ...) before trying to match the keyword:

```
Tests.Group001 GeneralTests
==============================================================================
Scenario: No template operation selected                              | FAIL |
No keyword with name 'But page does not contain a no template operation selected error message' found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I run the tests using a straight-forward:

```
pybot ../Tests
```

My sample test file is:

```
*** settings ***

Library     Selenium2Library
Library     DatabaseLibrary
Library     kw_common

*** Test Cases ***

Scenario: No template operation selected
    Given I have logged in and I have selected to perform template configuration
    When I do not select a template operation
    But page does not contain a no template operation selected error message
    And I press the next button
    Then I should not see a template operation selected error message


*** Keywords ***

I have logged in and I have selected to perform template configuration
    Log     Given I have logged in and I have selected to perform template configuration

I do not select a template operation
    Log     No template operation selected

page does not contain a no template operation selected error message
    Page Should Not Contain     'ddTemplateOperation' is required.

I press the next button
    Click Element               xpath=//input[contains(@id,'next')]

I should not see a template operation selected error message
    Page Should Contain     'ddTemplateOperation' is required.
```

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In case someone stumbles across this thread like me, please be advised that `But` keyword is also dropped now, if you follow the link in Harri's answer: > Prefixes Given, When, Then, And and But are dropped when matching keywords are searched, if no match with the full name is found.

Answer (score 5):

From the official documentation http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#ignoring-given-when-then-and-but-prefixes :

> Prefixes Given, When, Then and And are dropped when matching keywords
>   are searched

So `page does not contain a no template operation selected error message` keyword needs to be renamed to `But page does not contain a no template operation selected error message`.

Comment: Many thanks for the reference, Harri. I see the problem now. The video, [Introduction to Selenium 2 Library and Robot Framework](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHQVPeiBWEQ), shows that `But ` could be used as a Gherkin keyword that would be (optionally) discarded before attempting a keyword match, but this is not the case and caused the failure. Thanks again.

Comment: Is there 2 spaces between Given and the rest of the phrase or only one space?